# Java waited 20 hours before producing OutOfMemory error?

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a complex piece of Java mixed with Scala code that reads in an input file and creates numerous data structures while processing lines one-by-one, including a hash table of all substrings up to length 10 from the input.

I initially ran the code with the `-Xmx4g` switch, and the code took **20 hours** before returning an OOM error, and did not make it all the way through the file.

I then ran the code with `-Xmx32g` and the code processed all lines from the file in **8 minutes** and then proceeded to continue processing the data structures that were read.  After 8 minutes, the resident memory used by Java was ~21GB.

My question is: Why didn't Java return the OOM error within 8 minutes?  What was it doing for 20 hours?

Comment: Constantly garbage-collecting.

Comment: Memory consumption of `String.substring()` highly depends on Java version (before or after `1.7.0_06`) and if your substrings cover most of the original string or only a small part of the original string. Pre `1.7.0_06` substrings are backed by the same char[] from original string - the whole string keeps in memory but is shared by all substrings. With `1.7.0_06` substring creates new char arrays.

Comment: @FabianBarney: I wonder why they did that. The old approach seems to be much more sensible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Most propably because the old approach often lead to "memory leaks" with small substrings of huge original strings. While this could be addressed with explicit passing the substring result through the `String(String) ` constructor it was not intuitive.

Comment: Sure, but the amount of garbage generated is going to be the same in both cases --- all I did was increase the maximum heap size --- so why is so much more "work" being done when the heap size is limited? And what is the general takeaway here?  Should the heap size always be made as large as possible?  Why doesn't Java do this by default?

Comment: Also, this is Java 1.6.0_32, required because of certain constructs used in the code that are not 1.7 compatible :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, I am willing to bet that the OutOfMemoryError you faced was labelled "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". Independent if my bet was correct, the description of the situation matches exactly to what happened underneath:

- You loaded some data into the memory
- GC kicked in and cleaned some of it. During each time GC did its job, it paused the application threads.
- You loaded some more, triggering further GCs, but after each GC, less and less memory was recovered.
- The frequency of the garbage collection increased, up to the point where very little real progress was made
- JVM has a built-in safety net to catch those situations - whenever you spend more than 98% of the time in GC and are able to recover only 2% or less heap, the  "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error is thrown.

To detect such situations, you can turn on GC log (-verbose:gc or -XX:+PrintGCDetails for example) and keep an eye on the pause times.

Comment: Thanks! Can you possibly provide more detail on the JVM "safety net"? Over what time horizon is the "98%" calculated? Last 5 minutes, last hour? Is this a recent addition to the JVM?

Comment: On Oracle public documentation there are no detailed references to the period used - so the best source for truth would be to dig into the OpenJDK source code to find the answer. But this is not a recent addition, it was present already at least in JDK6

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collection is non-deterministic and complicated.  That, combined with other things such as the JIT compilation make precise memory usage patterns hard to predict and replicate.

You mentioned that it's including Scala?  That makes things even more interesting.  The "nice" functional constructs may be generating more garbage than it appears.  Even little things like wrapping objects in Option-s need additional memory that has to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a Garbage Collector thread. If it finds that it can collect enough garbage to free up space it will do so.

So, I recommend using visual VM and monitor the time spent garbage collecting the next time.